# What does the 'symbol' pipe do in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using pipes in angular to format some numbers into pound currency.
This is the line of code I am using to do it:

`<td>{{ product.price | currency:'GBP' : 'symbol' : '1.2-2' }}</td>`

This works but if you remove the 'symbol' so that it reads

`<td>{{ product.price | currency:'GBP' : '1.2-2' }}</td>`

It still works. So what is the 'symbol' pipe actually doing, I couldn't find any documentation for it online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the docs here: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

symbol(default): Show the symbol (such as $)